# A question about Maxwell's Equations

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

[These notes on Electromagnetism](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/em.html) (chapter 3.1.2, section "A Solenoid") say the following:

> We solve Ampère's law in differential form. Anywhere other than
> the surface of the solenoid, we have $\mathbf{J}=0$ and
> $$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\frac{dB}{dr}=0\quad\Rightarrow \quad B(r)=\text{constant}$$

Why does $\nabla\times B=0$ imply that $\frac{dB}{dr}=0$?

Comment: It is given that B only has a z-component. So apply curl you get that the x and y derivatives of B are both zero. So the r derivative must also be 0 (since r is a function of  x and y).

Comment: @BruceGreetham why not make that an answer?